# Android: Avoid phone restart when clicking home button

Tags: android, restart, onpause, android-homebutton

I'm programming an app, and I have to solve this problem... Being in any of the activities, when clicking the home button the phone restarts, and I don't want that to happen.

I know that clicking the home button brings the app to the background, and from the Android Lifecycle I would say that OnPause is called. Maybe I could fix the problem using this OnPause() method, but I don't know exactly what to do.

I've included the following logs in each activity:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() 
{
    Log.d(tag, "MYonPause is called");
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() 
{
    Log.d(tag, "MYonStop is called");
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    Log.d(tag, "MYonDestroy is called");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And here is my LogCat just after clicking the home button:

```
07-17 19:40:20.556: V/ActivityManager(1378): destroyActivityLocked, com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.destroyActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3332)
07-17 19:40:20.556: V/ActivityManager(1378): destroyActivityLocked, com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.trimApplications(ActivityManagerService.java:14511)
07-17 19:40:20.556: V/ActivityManager(1378): destroyActivityLocked, com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.finishReceiver(ActivityManagerService.java:12421)
07-17 19:40:20.556: V/ActivityManager(1378): destroyActivityLocked, android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:346)
07-17 19:40:20.556: V/ActivityManager(1378): destroyActivityLocked, com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1642)
07-17 19:40:20.566: V/ActivityManager(1378): destroyActivityLocked, android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
07-17 19:40:20.566: D/MyActivity(26362): MYonDestroy is called
07-17 19:40:20.566: V/ActivityManager(1378): destroyActivityLocked, dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
07-17 19:40:20.616: D/WindowManagerImpl(26362): finishRemoveViewLocked, mViews[0]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40683a18
07-17 19:40:20.716: D/libEGL(26672): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
07-17 19:40:20.726: D/WindowManagerImpl(1378): finishRemoveViewLocked, mViews[1]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40a48fa0
07-17 19:40:20.726: I/ActivityManager(1378): Displayed com.htc.launcher/.Launcher: +1s947ms
07-17 19:40:20.776: D/libEGL(26672): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
07-17 19:40:20.816: V/ActivityManager(1378): Checking to restart com.htc.launcher.Launcher: changed=0x0, handles=0x2a3
07-17 19:40:20.816: V/ActivityManager(1378): oldConfig={ scale=1.0 imsi=214/1 loc=en_ES touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=1 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=657 skin=default fontsize=3}
07-17 19:40:20.816: V/ActivityManager(1378): newConfig={ scale=1.0 imsi=214/1 loc=en_ES touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=1 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=657 skin=default fontsize=3}
07-17 19:40:20.826: D/MyActivity(26362): MYonStop is called
07-17 19:40:20.836: D/libEGL(26672): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
07-17 19:40:20.846: D/libEGL(26672): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
07-17 19:40:20.936: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
07-17 19:40:20.946: I/RosieUtility(25755): disable self killer: mEnabled=1
07-17 19:40:20.956: D/FxWidgetProvider(25755): row 4
07-17 19:40:20.956: I/RosieUtility(25755): enable self killer: mEnabled=0
07-17 19:40:20.966: D/WidgetProviderInfoCollector(26672): more than one style shared the same component! Return the first one found.
07-17 19:40:21.276: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
07-17 19:40:21.286: I/RosieUtility(25755): disable self killer: mEnabled=1
07-17 19:40:21.286: D/FxWidgetProvider(25755): row 1
07-17 19:40:21.286: I/RosieUtility(25755): enable self killer: mEnabled=0
07-17 19:40:21.326: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
07-17 19:40:21.336: I/RosieUtility(25755): disable self killer: mEnabled=1
07-17 19:40:21.336: D/FxWidgetProvider(25755): row 1
07-17 19:40:21.336: I/RosieUtility(25755): enable self killer: mEnabled=0
07-17 19:40:21.476: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
07-17 19:40:21.476: I/RosieUtility(25755): disable self killer: mEnabled=1
07-17 19:40:21.476: D/FxWidgetProvider(25755): row 1
07-17 19:40:21.486: I/RosieUtility(25755): enable self killer: mEnabled=0
07-17 19:40:21.577: D/szipinf(26672): Initializing inflate state
07-17 19:40:22.047: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
07-17 19:40:22.047: I/RosieUtility(25755): disable self killer: mEnabled=1
07-17 19:40:22.047: D/FxWidgetProvider(25755): row 1
07-17 19:40:22.047: I/RosieUtility(25755): enable self killer: mEnabled=0
07-17 19:40:22.417: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
07-17 19:40:22.427: I/RosieUtility(25755): disable self killer: mEnabled=1
07-17 19:40:22.427: D/FxWidgetProvider(25755): row 1
07-17 19:40:22.437: I/RosieUtility(25755): enable self killer: mEnabled=0
07-17 19:40:22.477: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
07-17 19:40:22.477: I/RosieUtility(25755): disable self killer: mEnabled=1
07-17 19:40:22.477: D/FxWidgetProvider(25755): row 1
07-17 19:40:22.477: I/RosieUtility(25755): enable self killer: mEnabled=0
07-17 19:40:22.908: D/dalvikvm(26672): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 325K, 49% free 3739K/7303K, external 5261K/5309K, paused 39ms
07-17 19:40:22.988: D/dalvikvm(26672): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 13K, 49% free 3731K/7303K, external 5581K/6969K, paused 36ms
07-17 19:40:23.178: D/dalvikvm(26672): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 49K, 50% free 3681K/7303K, external 7187K/8975K, paused 39ms
07-17 19:40:23.228: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
07-17 19:40:23.228: I/RosieUtility(25755): disable self killer: mEnabled=1
07-17 19:40:23.228: D/FxWidgetProvider(25755): row 1
07-17 19:40:23.238: I/RosieUtility(25755): enable self killer: mEnabled=0
07-17 19:40:23.248: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
07-17 19:40:23.258: I/RosieUtility(25755): disable self killer: mEnabled=1
07-17 19:40:23.258: D/FxWidgetProvider(25755): row 1
07-17 19:40:23.258: I/RosieUtility(25755): enable self killer: mEnabled=0
07-17 19:40:23.288: D/HomeLoaders(26672):   --> starting applications loader
07-17 19:40:23.428: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
07-17 19:40:23.478: E/mode10(26672): PlayMarker fail, marker 'intro_to_up' not found in button.shortcut
07-17 19:40:23.508: E/mode10(26672): Fail to load timeline from asset.
07-17 19:40:23.508: E/mode10(26672): Timeline load failure
07-17 19:40:23.669: D/FxScreen(26672): item count: 1
07-17 19:40:23.699: D/MessagingShortcutReceiver(25766): keep hiding shortcut bubble
07-17 19:40:23.699: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
07-17 19:40:23.719: I/ActivityManager(1378): Start proc com.htc.android.mail for broadcast com.htc.android.mail/.AppMonitorReceiver: pid=26692 uid=9997 gids={3003, 1015}
07-17 19:40:23.769: E/mode10(26672): PlayMarker fail, marker 'intro_to_up' not found in button.shortcut
07-17 19:40:23.809: E/mode10(26672): Fail to load timeline from asset.
07-17 19:40:23.819: E/mode10(26672): Timeline load failure
07-17 19:40:23.829: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
07-17 19:40:23.849: D/Utilities(26672): createIconThumbnail # iconWidth: 72,iconHeight: 72,width: 72,height: 72
07-17 19:40:23.929: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
07-17 19:40:23.939: I/RosieUtility(25755): disable self killer: mEnabled=1
07-17 19:40:23.949: D/FxWidgetProvider(25755): row 81
07-17 19:40:23.949: I/RosieUtility(25755): enable self killer: mEnabled=0
07-17 19:40:23.979: D/StatusBarPolicy(1556): Network Type: 2
07-17 19:40:24.009: W/dalvikvm(26692): Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/com.htc.framework.jar'
07-17 19:40:24.019: W/dalvikvm(26692): Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/com.htc.android.pimlib.jar'
07-17 19:40:24.019: W/dalvikvm(26692): Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/com.htc.android.easopen.jar'
07-17 19:40:24.019: D/FxScreen(26672): item count: 1
07-17 19:40:24.079: E/mode10(26672): PlayMarker fail, marker 'intro_to_up' not found in button.shortcut
07-17 19:40:24.129: E/mode10(26672): Fail to load timeline from asset.
07-17 19:40:24.139: E/mode10(26672): Timeline load failure
07-17 19:40:24.169: D/Utilities(26672): createIconThumbnail # iconWidth: 72,iconHeight: 72,width: 72,height: 72
07-17 19:40:24.199: D/MessagingShortcut(25766): updateMsgShortcut, msg count> 0
07-17 19:40:24.209: D/MessagingShortcut(25766): mPresentUnreadCount: 0
07-17 19:40:24.209: D/MessagingShortcut(25766): setMsgShortcutDrawable> 0
07-17 19:40:24.219: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
07-17 19:40:24.279: I/ActivityThread(26692): Pub com.htc.android.mail.attachmentprovider: com.htc.android.mail.provider.AttachmentProvider
07-17 19:40:24.409: D/FxScreen(26672): item count: 2
07-17 19:40:24.499: E/mode10(26672): PlayMarker fail, marker 'intro_to_up' not found in button.shortcut
07-17 19:40:24.509: I/ActivityThread(26692): Pub mail: com.htc.android.mail.MailProvider
07-17 19:40:24.549: E/mode10(26672): Fail to load timeline from asset.
07-17 19:40:24.549: E/mode10(26672): Timeline load failure
07-17 19:40:24.569: D/Utilities(26672): createIconThumbnail # iconWidth: 72,iconHeight: 72,width: 72,height: 72
07-17 19:40:24.599: I/ActivityThread(26692): Pub com.htc.android.mail.MailCarousel: com.htc.android.mail.MailCarousel
07-17 19:40:24.629: I/ActivityThread(26692): Pub htceas: com.htc.android.mail.eassvc.core.EASProvider
07-17 19:40:24.650: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
07-17 19:40:24.650: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
07-17 19:40:24.650: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
07-17 19:40:24.660: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
07-17 19:40:24.670: D/AppMonitorReceiver(26692): 06021143 onReceive>Intent { act=com.htc.launcher.action.ACTION_ITEM_ADDED cmp=com.htc.android.mail/.AppMonitorReceiver (has extras) },#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;launchFlags=0x10200000;component=com.htc.android.mail/.MailListTab;end
07-17 19:40:24.670: D/AppMonitorReceiver(26692): 06021143 update mail shortcut>
07-17 19:40:24.700: D/MessagingShortcutReceiver(25766): keep hiding shortcut bubble
07-17 19:40:24.710: D/AppMonitorReceiver(26692): 06021143 onReceive>Intent { act=com.htc.launcher.action.ACTION_ITEM_ADDED cmp=com.htc.android.mail/.AppMonitorReceiver (has extras) },#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;launchFlags=0x10200000;component=com.android.camera/.CameraEntry;end
07-17 19:40:24.730: D/MessagingShortcutReceiver(25766): keep hiding shortcut bubble
07-17 19:40:24.740: D/FxScreen(26672): item count: 1
07-17 19:40:24.790: D/Database(26692): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.htc.android.mail/databases/mail.db, flag = 6, file size = 76800
07-17 19:40:24.840: I/Database(26692): sqlite returned: error code = 0, msg = Recovered 71 frames from WAL file /data/data/com.htc.android.mail/databases/mail.db-wal
07-17 19:40:24.870: D/Database(26692): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.htc.android.mail/databases/mail.db, mode: wal, disk free size: 485 M, handle: 0x353470
07-17 19:40:25.000: D/dalvikvm(1378): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1482K, 34% free 11322K/17095K, external 2108K/2395K, paused 233ms
07-17 19:40:25.020: D/CursorWindow(26692): Allocate Cursor Window, size = 4096 KB
07-17 19:40:25.020: D/AppMonitorReceiver(26692): 06021143 onReceive>Intent { act=com.htc.launcher.action.ACTION_ITEM_ADDED cmp=com.htc.android.mail/.AppMonitorReceiver (has extras) },#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;launchFlags=0x10200000;component=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity;end
07-17 19:40:25.030: D/MessagingShortcut(25766): Send UNREAD_MESSAGE_COUNT broadcast: count=0
07-17 19:40:25.030: E/mode10(26672): PlayMarker fail, marker 'intro_to_up' not found in button.shortcut
07-17 19:40:25.060: E/mode10(26672): Fail to load timeline from asset.
07-17 19:40:25.060: E/mode10(26672): Timeline load failure
07-17 19:40:25.070: D/Utilities(26672): createIconThumbnail # iconWidth: 72,iconHeight: 72,width: 72,height: 72
07-17 19:40:25.190: D/FxScreen(26672): item count: 3
07-17 19:40:25.230: D/dalvikvm(26672): GetFieldID: unable to find field Ljava/util/Hashtable;.loadFactor:F
07-17 19:40:25.230: D/MessagingShortcut(25766): updateMsgShortcut, msg count> 0
07-17 19:40:25.250: D/MessagingShortcut(25766): mPresentUnreadCount: 0
07-17 19:40:25.250: D/MessagingShortcut(25766): setMsgShortcutDrawable> 0
07-17 19:40:25.620: D/dalvikvm(26692): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 178K, 46% free 3017K/5511K, external 0K/0K, paused 595ms
07-17 19:40:25.630: E/mode10(26672): Fail to load timeline from asset.
07-17 19:40:25.630: E/mode10(26672): Timeline load failure
07-17 19:40:25.721: I/FxListViewCollection(26672): FxListViewCollection is created with handle 17239736
07-17 19:40:25.721: I/FxListViewCollection(26672): FxListViewCollection is created with handle 17072072
07-17 19:40:25.721: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
07-17 19:40:25.741: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
07-17 19:40:26.311: D/FxScreen(26672): item count: 2
07-17 19:40:26.311: E/mode10(26672): PlayMarker fail, marker 'intro_to_up' not found in button.shortcut
07-17 19:40:26.391: E/mode10(26672): Fail to load timeline from asset.
07-17 19:40:26.391: E/mode10(26672): Timeline load failure
07-17 19:40:26.391: D/Utilities(26672): createIconThumbnail # iconWidth: 72,iconHeight: 72,width: 72,height: 72
07-17 19:40:26.441: D/dalvikvm(26672): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1110K, 44% free 4408K/7815K, external 9207K/9227K, paused 13ms+9ms
07-17 19:40:26.531: D/dalvikvm(26672): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 58K, 45% free 4349K/7815K, external 9207K/9227K, paused 77ms
07-17 19:40:26.621: D/dalvikvm(26672): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 60K, 46% free 4288K/7815K, external 9227K/11275K, paused 69ms
07-17 19:40:26.762: D/dalvikvm(26672): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 23K, 46% free 4278K/7815K, external 9270K/11275K, paused 45ms
07-17 19:40:26.792: D/FxScreen(26672): item count: 3
07-17 19:40:26.842: E/mode10(26672): PlayMarker fail, marker 'intro_to_up' not found in button.shortcut
07-17 19:40:26.892: E/mode10(26672): Fail to load timeline from asset.
07-17 19:40:26.902: E/mode10(26672): Timeline load failure
07-17 19:40:26.902: D/Utilities(26672): createIconThumbnail # iconWidth: 72,iconHeight: 72,width: 72,height: 72
07-17 19:40:26.972: D/StatusBarPolicy(1556): Network Type: 2
07-17 19:40:27.062: D/FxScreen(26672): item count: 4
07-17 19:40:27.102: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
07-17 19:40:27.122: E/mode10(26672): PlayMarker fail, marker 'intro_to_up' not found in button.shortcut
07-17 19:40:27.162: E/mode10(26672): Fail to load timeline from asset.
07-17 19:40:27.162: E/mode10(26672): Timeline load failure
07-17 19:40:27.192: D/Utilities(26672): createIconThumbnail # iconWidth: 72,iconHeight: 72,width: 72,height: 72
07-17 19:40:27.282: D/FxScreen(26672): item count: 5
07-17 19:40:27.322: D/MessagingShortcut(25766): Send UNREAD_MESSAGE_COUNT broadcast: count=0
07-17 19:40:27.322: E/mode10(26672): PlayMarker fail, marker 'intro_to_up' not found in button.shortcut
07-17 19:40:27.352: E/mode10(26672): Fail to load timeline from asset.
07-17 19:40:27.352: E/mode10(26672): Timeline load failure
07-17 19:40:27.372: D/Utilities(26672): createIconThumbnail # iconWidth: 72,iconHeight: 72,width: 72,height: 72
07-17 19:40:27.502: D/FxScreen(26672): item count: 4
...
```

Comment: do you want to restart the phone or it is restarting when you click on the home button?

Comment: Put some logs in your onPause, onStop and onDestroy of your activity, and paste the logcat before the restart happens to your question

Comment: Good question, subject line says your phone is getting restart if press home button, But Question says you want to switch off phone. Ambiguity on its best.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity on my question. I don't want the phone to get restarted, and that is what happens when clicking on the home button

Comment: @acm46 so what is your code doing? Add it to your question

Comment: You have a severly broken phone / android installation.  Nothing a third party application does is supposed to be able to restart the phone intentionally or unintentionally.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I've put some logs and I've written the logcat just when the phone restarts

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, when 'HOME' button is pressed the activity's `onStop()` method is called. You can use the following piece of code to override (monitor) it:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() 
{
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(tag, "MYonStop is called");
    // insert here your instructions
}
```